# How can I handle translations for data stored in the database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, translation

I am using Ruby on Rails 3.2.2 and the I18n 0.6.0 gem. I would like to internazionalize some data stored in the database. That is, I have an `articles` database table (related to an `Article` class) with `title` and `description` columns (attributes) and I would like to handle translation concerns by caring performance and search functionalities throughout the system.

**How can I do that?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This recent railscast may help you:

http://railscasts.com/episodes/338-globalize3